# Using INDIRECT to dynamically select a cell in a sheet in a different workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to reference a cell ($C$3) in a sheet in a different workbook dynamically. For example, lets say I have a column of the sheet names in Workbook1 (C4:C35) in Workbook2. Using a cell in Workbook2, how could I get find a cell in Workbook1 while going down each record of sheet names in Workbook1 (C4:C35) in Workbook2. It might make more sense if I type out what I think the answer should be using indirect (could use something else, but this just came to mind first).

Typical format:

```
='[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$3
```

What I think the answer should be, but it doesn't work:

```
= INDIRECT ( “ ‘ “ & A5 & C4 & “ ‘ ! “ & $C$3 )
```

Cell Values:

```
A5 = [Workbook1.xlsx]
C4 = Start of column of sheets in Workbook2 (C4) (out of C4:C35)
$C$3 = The cell I want to retrieve
```

I'm using a cell for the other workbook because indirect doesn't like the brackets. I am also using extra spaces so it's easier to read the indirect.

Comment: I think it would be `=INDIRECT("'"&A5&C4&"'! $C$3")`.

Comment: @Harun24hr thank you it worked. syntax was a little off I guess

Comment: If you wish, I can post as answer.